# Can you help me identify this component?

Tags: pcb, components, surface-mount

I don't know what is this B104D and what it does.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a Coilcraft inductor.

Giveaways:

- "L" as a schematic symbol often denotes inductors.
- The logo on the inductor is Coilcraft's logo, it's quite unique so it's easy to identify.

After looking at some of their products, it is most likely [LPS8045B](https://www.coilcraft.com/en-us/products/power/shielded-inductors/ferrite-drum/lps/lps8045b/).

The 104 is the dash number, which denotes a 104 = 10 * 10^4 nH = 100 µH inductance.

As for what it does - I have no idea, it could be used as an inductor for a switch mode power supply, that's what they are marketed for, but users always come up with ideas to use products not the way they were thought for in the first place.

Comment: Excellent answer! I was going to comment a very similar answer myself but you were faster :)

Comment: @uriyabsc thanks for improving the formatting of mine.

Comment: Of course, you're welcome!